# Making a program to display 15 random, simple addition and subtraction problems in java

Tags: java, class, math, methods, operators

**I am working on a project where the desired output is:**

```
Question 1: 12 + 0 = 12
Question 2: 6 + 12 = 18
Question 3: 3 + 8 = 11
Question 4: 11 - 0 = 11
Question 5: 8 + 7 = 15
Question 6: 8 - 3 = 5
Question 7: 8 - 2 = 6
Question 8: 12 - 9 = 3
Question 9: 0 + 10 = 10
Question 10: 4 + 5 = 9
Question 11: 2 + 1 = 3
Question 12: 1 + 12 = 13
Question 13: 12 + 0 = 12
Question 14: 10 - 1 = 9
Question 15: 11 - 8 = 3
```

**Where the operands and operators are randomized. I need to use two different classes in this project and i am having the most difficulty with the programmer defined class called Questions, containing the accessor methods and instance variables.**

**Addition** - two operands, both in the range 0-12

**Subtraction** - two operands, the first in the range 6-12, and the second, less than or equal to the first operand. (This is to avoid negative numbers)

**Generate a class that randomly generates addition or subtraction problems**

SPECS:

**3 instance variables**: int operand1, int operand2, char operator

**3 accessor methods**: getOperand1, getOperand2, getOperator**

**Also a toString method that returns a string containing the question(but not the answer) The format should be operand1, a space, operator, a space, operand2, a space and an equal sign.**

So far i have this:

```
package proj3;

public class Question {

private int operand1;
private int operand2;
private char operator;

public static int operand1(){
    int num;
    num = (int)(Math.random() * 13);
    return num;
}   
public static int operand2(){
    int num;
    num = (int)(Math.random() * 13);
    return num;

}
public String toString(){
    System.out.println(operand1 + operator + operand2 + "=");
    return null;
    }
```

}

I am not sure if i did the operand1 method correctly or not, also i am not sure how to go about creating the rest of the methods in this class. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Each `Question` instance will represent one question. Therefore you should generate the random values in the constructor, when the instance is created:

```
public Question() {
    // generate the random values and store them in instance variables
}
```

- first generate the operator
- based on the operator, you can generate the operands
- assign the generated values into the instance variables

The accessor methods should be instance methods, not static, and they should just return the corresponding instance variables.

`toString()` shouldn't print anything - it should just return the `String`, instead of `null` as you currently have. Also you should add some spaces to the string, so that it has the desired format.

So your class will look like this:

```
public class Question {
    private int operand1;
    private int operand2;
    private char operator;

    public Question() {
        // generate the random values and store them in instance variables
    }

    public int getOperand1() {
        return operand1;
    }
    public int getOperand2() {
        return operand2;
    }
    public char getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return operand1 + " " + operator + " " + operand2 + " =";
    }
}
```

If you create an instance of `Random`, you can use more convenient methods to obtain random values:

```
Random r = new Random();
boolean randomBoolean = r.nextBoolean();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(13);
```

**UPDATE:**

In your attempt you did

```
int num;
num = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
```

That creates a local variable `num` and assigns a random number in the range `0..1`. This variable is local to the constructor, it isn't stored anywhere else. What you need to do is assign values to the instance variables `operand1`, `operand2` and `operator`.

First you decide the operator by getting a random boolean:

```
Random r = new Random();
if (r.nextBoolean()) {
    // addition
} else {
    // subtraction
}
```

Then in each branch of the `if` you generate the appropriate random values and store them to the instance variables. Also store the operator.

As an example:

To generate a number `0..99`, you would use `r.nextInt(100)`.

To generate a number `80..99`, you would use `r.nextInt(20) + 80`.

I will leave the last details to you:

```
public Question() {

    Random r = new Random();

    if (r.nextBoolean()) {
        operator = '+';
        operand1 = r.nextInt(13);
        operand2 = // your code
    } else {
        operator = '-';
        operand1 = // your code
        operand2 = // your code
    }
}
```

You can test the output like this:

```
Question q = new Question();
System.out.println("first operand: " + q.getOperand1());
System.out.println("full question: " + q); // toString() will be automatically used here
```

Comment: thank you for the help, the toString makes sense to me but they way the rest of the methods are written right now, it doesnt seem like they are set up to generate random numbers or operators (+,-).

Comment: @MichaelCera They don't - the accessor (`get...()`) methods should simply return the instance variable values. All random generation logic should be in the constructor, where the comment is. I left that implementation up to you, this was just to show how the class should be structured. If you follow the instructions here plus the assignment requirements for the random generated values, it should be easy to implement it. If you get stuck, feel free to ask, but please post your attempt (edit it into the question).

Comment: @MichaelCera You can use `Random#nextBoolean()` and `Random#nextInt(int)` for more convenient random value generation (see the end of my answer).

Comment: @MichaelCera The reason why the accessor methods shouldn't generate values is that they are dependent on each other - `getOperand1()` would need to know the operator, and `getOperand2()` would need to know operator *and* operand1. So you would either need to always call them in the correct order, or pass the values to them. Either way, it doesn't make much sense to do it like that. Plus, they are *getters* - they shouldn't modify the values, they should only return them. This is why I suggested to generate all the values in one place in the constructor.

Comment: So far i have this where you left the comment:
public Question() {
 // generate the random values and store them in instance    variables
     int num;
     num = (int) (Math.random() * 2);

    }

and i am gettin the output:
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0
Question : 0

based on my other class which is:
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
   System.out.println("Question" + " : " + Question.getOperand1());
  }

Comment: Thanks alot after looking more deeply into it i finally got it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelCera You should accept the poster's answer to appreciate his hard work!

Comment: @Siddhartha I think the OP isn't coming back :) Thanks for notifying him though.

Comment: i did just dont know how to tag your username

Comment: @MichaelCera Tagging is done by typing @ and first few letters of someone's username, then you can press tab to complete. About the accept: please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Choosing whether to accept an answer is of course entirely up to the asker.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want 2 methods for each operand, a getter method - `getOperand1()` and a `generateOperand1()` (which is what you're calling `operand1()` above)

For random generation, you could take an Enum argument `typeOfOperation`, and then using a `switch` statement you could generate the operands accordingly.

E.g.

```
void generateOperand1(OperationEnum typeOfOperation) {

  switch (typeOfOperation) {

    case OperationEnum.ADDITION
        operand1 = // logic to generate random number
        break;
    case OperationEnum.SUBTRACTION
        operand1 = // logic to generate random number
  }
}
```

Similarly, you can create a `generateOperator` depending on the type of operation.